# Unable to install WSUS to windows 2012 r2 server

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, wsus

This is on a VM in Hyper-V running under the Failover Cluster Manager.  The VM in question has all updates applied to it.  It is not a new server as it is also my Anti-Virus Administration Server.  I am just trying to add WSUS to it.

Whenever I try to add WSUS via feature/roles I get:

*“The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. the operation cannot be completed because the server that you specified requires a restart.”*

After researching it seems to be a GPO issue relating to MS Locking down NT Services not being able to be logon as a service in 2012 R2.  This is great and fits our companies security polices but I can't find a work around on how to do the WSUS install.  I've seen blog posts that says they have done it but don't list how.  I even found a article from microsofts powershell guy and he didn't even mention that this might be and issue, so I tried:
*Install-WindowsFeature -Name UpdateServices -IncludeManagementTools –WhatIf*
and get this:
*Install-WindowsFeature : The request to list features available on the specified server failed.
The operation cannot be completed, because the server that you specified requires a restart.*

Any help on how to get this resolved would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Les Burditt

Comment: `“The request to add or remove features on the specified server failed. the operation cannot be completed because the server that you specified requires a restart.”` - Have you restarted the server?

Comment: Yes, multiple times and still get the same error.

Comment: Seems there is a pending installation of other software keeping the server in a "need to restart" state. This could be a hotfix, or botched earlier software installation, that keeps being re-applied on each reboot so the machine never reaches a "idle" state where it is ready for a change of roles/features. Could even be malware or a root-kit that is causing this. You may be able to find some information in the Event Log but usually this is looking for a needle in a haystack. I strongly suggest you spin up a fresh VM for WSUS. Combining applications on the same VM isn't a good idea anyway IMHO